# MASM x64 Assembly printf float

Tags: assembly, printf, masm, masm32, masm64

```
.data
temp real4 ?
fmtStr byte 'Result is: %d', 10, 0
fmtStr2 byte 'Result is: %f', 10, 0
i real4 ?

.code
printFloat proc
    sub rsp, 20h
    movsd xmm1, [temp]
    lea rcx, fmtStr2 
    call printf
    add rsp, 20h;
    ret
printFloat endp
```

Result is always 0.0000000. How i can get value real4 like 5.3434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs here.

`temp` is a `real4` but it should be a `real8`, or it can stay a `real4` but then we need to convert it to a double to pass it to `printf` (varargs functions don't accept floats, they have to be double).

The floating point argument also has to be copied in the corresponding integer argument, so `rdx` in this case.

Also, `20h` is the wrong thing to subtract from `rsp`, it will leave the stack unaligned and `printf` may not like that (it didn't like that on my system). If you have that here, you may have it in other functions too, and some combinations would accidentally result in a correct alignment anyway but for the wrong reason.

The code you showed never assigned a non-zero to `temp` but I assume you did that elsewhere.

This code worked for me:

```
.data
temp real8 5.4321
fmtStr2 byte 'Result is: %f', 10, 0

.code

extrn printf : proc

printFloat proc
    sub rsp, 28h
    movsd xmm1, [temp]
    mov rdx, [temp]
    lea rcx, fmtStr2 
    call printf
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
printFloat endp

end
```

Comment: i dont know why but with 20h and your code it works on my system. Thanks!

Comment: @F1G1 possibly you called this function from a function that already misaligned the stack, then the two misalignments can cancel. Or on your system `printf` may be less picky about alignment.